# Is it possible to have more than one geo_point index in a ElasticSearch document?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping, elasticsearch-query

I have the following mapping for a type:

```
{
    "myType":
        "properties": {
            "departure": {"type": "geo_point" },
            "destination": {"type": "geo_point" }
        }
}
```

I can insert documents without any trouble. But when I try to filter them by `departure` I get no results and when I try by `destination` it works just fine.

So the question is: Is it possible to have more than one `geo_point` in the same document?

EDIT:

**Sample document:**

```
{
    "departure": {
        "lat": -23.682,
        "lon": -46.595
    },
    "destination": {
        "lat": -22.895,
        "lon": -47.030
    }
}
```

**Sample query:**

```
  curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/tripda/trip/_search?pretty=true' -d '
{
  "query": {
    "filtered" : {
        "query" : {
            "match_all" : {}
        },
        "filter" : {
            "geo_distance" : {
               "distance" : "15km",
                "departure" : {
                    "lat" : -23.682,
                    "lon" : -46.595
                }
            }
        }
     }
  }
}'
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yes it's possible. Can you show us some sample documents and how your queries look like?

Comment: And it is also possible with nested fields?

Comment: @Val you saved my day! Nested query was giving me trouble but normal fields work just fine! Thanks for the insight! :)